# What is the syntax for converting a sample JSON request body (not a response) to a List of c# objects?

Tags: c#, json, list, object

This is, I'm sure, a ridiculously simple-minded question, but I'm scope-locked and I can't figure it out

I'm using a c# list of objects to compose a JSON request body

for example, there is a Microsoft Request Body JSON sample that looks like this:

> [   {
> "op": "add",
> "path": "/fields/System.Title",
> "value": "Sample task"   } ]

For this sample, I extrapolated the Description body and my c# code looks like this (title and description are string variables)

> ```
> List<Object> flds = new List<Object>
> {
>   new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Title", value = title },
>   new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Description", value = description }
> };
>
> string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flds);
> ```

Now, I have a sample JSON request body that includes this:

> {    "op": "add",    "path": "/relations/-",    "value": {
> "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-forward",
> "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300",
> "attributes": {
> "comment": "Making a new link for the dependency"
> }    } }

I can't figure out how I need to render the "value" and all that follows it into the c# List. Do the string(s) need to include the quotes, colons, and braces?

> "value": {
> "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-forward",
> "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300",
> "attributes": {
> "comment": "Making a new link for the dependency"
> }    }

What am I missing? Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
List<Object> flds = new List<Object>
{
  new
  {
      op = "add",
      path = "/relations/-",
      value = new
      {
          rel = "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-forward",
          url = "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300",
          attributes = new
          {
            comment = "Making a new link for the dependency"
          }
      }
  }
};
```

The output of `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flds);`:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-forward",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300",
            "attributes": {
                "comment": "Making a new link for the dependency"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Essentially, every time you encounter curly brackets, you are dealing with another object.